# GatsbyJS optimize when to fetch images

Tags: gatsby

I love all the optimization Gatsby provides, but **I would like to have more control over *when* images are fetched**. How can I achieve this?

As an example case, think about a typical blog: many pages, a lot of text, few images.

**The default behavior in Gatsby is that images are lazy loaded** when you scroll to them, with a placeholder and transition (go to any Medium blog to see how this looks). I don't like this. If I loaded the page 30 seconds ago, there was plenty of time to send me the images already. It's unnecessary to show me a blurred up photo, I should have the real image by now.

**How to change this behavior?** The only thing I found in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/) is that I could mark my images as critical so they would start loading immediately. Marking all my images as critical would be bad for 2 reasons: first, it slows down the initial "First Meaningful Paint", as part of the bandwidth would be wasted loading images that are further down the page. Second, when links to other pages are prefetched, it again wastes bandwidth downloading large versions of images.

**Desired behavior** in my case would be to load critical resources of a page first, and non-critical resources of a page after that. When prefetching links, non-critical resources should not be loaded.

---

Edit: After help from Cyril and Derek, I'm now able to fetch images with a timeout. Now I have a weird problem:

https://epic-haibt-d9fc0a.netlify.com/

It's as if the meaning of "placeholder" and "actual image" is flipped for images which are fetched with the timeout. Relevant part of source [here](https://github.com/baobabKoodaa/blog/blob/pictureDelayExperiment/src/components/Blog/PictureDelay.js).

Comment: You can turn off the blur-up effect by appending `_noBase64` to your fragment expansions.

Comment: You mean images would still be lazyloaded, just without the blur up transition?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend existing React class & modify its behavior. I dig around the source of gatsby-image, and it looks like the props [`isVisible`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/a5de0b77a938f5f4880d42f8968e089248ed9603/packages/gatsby-image/src/index.js#L307) is responsible for loading image.

Would it be safe to say 'First Meaningful Paint' is completed once the document is completely loaded? If so, I think we can use `window.onload` as a trigger to load the image.

You can extend existing class like so:

```
import Image from 'gatsby-image'

class ImageDelay extends Image {
  componentDidMount() {

    // call the parent class' componentDidMount method
    // to preserve existing behavior
    super.componentDidMount();

    window.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        isVisible: true
      })
    }
  }
}

export default ImageDelay
```

Then use it as a normal Image component:

```
import ImageDelay from '../components/ImageDelay'

// somewhere on your page
<ImageDelay fluid={heroFluid} />
```

You can also add a delay using `setTimeout` instead of `window.onload`. If the user doesn't scroll into the image within a certain amount of time, it'll be loaded for them.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really promising for "regular" pages. However, my pages are transformed from markdown, so I can't figure out where to apply this. I opened  a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470505/gatsbyjs-customize-markdown-transformer

Comment: Ah you linked gatsby-image doc so I thought you were using that component. For gatsby markdown image, without modifying the source, I wonder if there’s something you can do in gatsby-browser..

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Hey Atte, I dug into `gatsby-remark-images`, and it looks like it doesnt have the 'lazy load' behavior like you described. Images are loaded instantly as soon as the page load -- is this still something you're looking to change?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally gave wrong information. I now realize the starter I'm working on is using both `gatsby-remark-images` (for blog posts) and `gatsby-image` (for main page). Because the blog posts had the blur-up effect, I thought that they were also lazy loading like the main page. Since they're not, no problem there. Just the main page to deal with. I'll try to adapt your answer for that later tonight.

Comment: I've put a 100 bounty on this question in case you are still interested in taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for the notice @AtteJuvonen! Now looking at this answer, I think the way I did it (extending existing component) is a bit hacky, perhaps a better way is to wrap gatsby-image in a new component and pass `critical` as a props to it & let it do what it should instead of hacking its internal state. It look like Cyril's giving you some great help, if you couldn't resolve it by the end of the week I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

You have errors by adding a constructor because the base class constructor has a `props` argument.

Calling the base constructor with arguments will fix this error

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loadPictures = this.loadPictures.bind(this);
}
```

Because gatsby use *Server-Side Rendering* `window` or `document` should be use with caution. See : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/ and https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5835. You should check if the `window` or `document` object exists first and then unsubscribe to event in order to avoid memory leak.

```
class PictureDelay extends Picture {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loadPictures = this.loadPictures.bind(this);
  }

  loadPictures() {
    console.log("Loading pictures...");
    this.setState({ isVisible: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("load", this.loadPictures);
      // window.setTimeout(this.loadPictures, 1000);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    super.componentWillUnmount();
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.removeEventListener("load", this.loadPictures);
    }
  }
}
```

---

By the way the page is not reloaded when using gatsby link. To improve performance, *Gatsby* uses internal mechanism to update the page and `window.load` event will not be fired and no event is fired when the page has updated. 
 See [#2906 - gatsby-link determine when loading is complete](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2906) and [#3415 - formalize API for hooking into page load lifecycle...](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3415)

Furthermore [inheritance is generally avoided in `React` application](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) and relying on internal behavior (the `isLoaded` state) is not guaranteed to work in future version. For these reasons I think it is better to use the `critical` property or to create your own `gatsby-image` implementation.

```
class PictureDelay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Picture critical={true} {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a old version of `gatsby-image` since `v2.0.29` it looks like you can force the visibility this way. This commit *fixes* this behavior : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/commit/1d5ccff73b0c6c0dffcb8f812e50f31b2d7b36ee#diff-5941a73c5d794b120294a0429b6351c1

Comment: I updated to the newest version now and it looks like it's working. (I had to comment out `super.componentWillUnmount` because it was causing an error where `super` somehow was undefined.)

Comment: I will heed your advice and just use `critical` for now, out of fear of things breaking with future versions. If a better answer doesn't come up I'll give you the bounty at the end of the week.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen In your Gatsby "photo book" starter, you don't use Gatsby-Image at all.  Why is that?

Comment: @BrentArias I don't remember which exact problems I had with gatsby-image, but there were several. Some were related to alignment of placeholders, some were related to performance. It was really easy to display images without gatsby-image, so I did that.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Thank you.  I'd love to ask more questions and perhaps contribute to your photo book starter (e.g. add photo-tagging and tag filtering option).  Please reach out if interested: `barias@axiscode.com`.